# How to: JOIN one column from one table to 2 columns in the other table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, join

First post... although I have referenced this site many times.  I have one table that contains two columns that use the employee ID#'s.  The other table has the employee's name and employee ID#. I am trying to get the employee name to come back for both columns in one table.

`Employee` table contains `EmployeeName` and `EmployeeID`
Jobs table contains employee # in the `JobSuperID` column and employee # in the `JobManID` column

```
Select EmployeeName
FROM [DBex].[dbo].[JobStatus] 
Right JOIN [DBex].[dbo].[Employees] 
  ON [DBex].[dbo].[Employees].EmployeeID = [DBex].[dbo].[Jobs].JobSuperID
Right JOIN [DBex].[dbo].[Employees] 
  ON  [DBex].[dbo].[Employees].EmployeeID = [DBex].[dbo].[Jobs].JobAcctManID
```

I have seen references to using `AS` but have not been able to get the syntax right. Also if I am only selecting `EmployeeName` how do I display both columns? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a little here, but it sounds like you have a table linking a supervisor to an employee by ID number, and you want to return the names of both employees.  If that is correct, the following should work:

```
Select s.EmployeeName as SuperName, m.EmployeeName as ManName
from Jobs a
left join Employees S
  on a.JobSuperID = S.EmployeeID
left join Employees M
  on a.JobManID = M.EmployeeID
```